# PHP redirect to localhost

Tags: php, apache, redirect, localhost

I have a live site and I want to redirect a page to my current machine I'm developing on. I tried the following

```
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header('Location: http://localhost/dev/test.php');
```

The redirection should NOT be done to the live server's localhost, but to my local machine I'm currently using to develop. This is simply to test a payment gateway I've added to my site (the payment gateway requires a valid URL to redirect to, hence I can't use localhost).

The payment gateway will redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/test.php
```

Which should then be redirected to my current machine:

```
http://localhost/dev/test.php
```

If php can't manage this, can I do this with apache redirects?
I also want to send all GET and POST parameters received at the live server to my local page.

Comment: The question is vague... Certainly you can send a redirection header to a client. The reserved hostname `localhost` is always resolved by the _client_, not by the server, so it will point to the client system. The whole flow is unclear so, that I am not sure if that helps...

Comment: Any live server CANT access your local machine.. I would also add BY ANY MEANS.. This is just not possible.. The localhost is just a server that is running on your system..and that wont be accessible to any of the live systems

Comment: unless you give the ipaddress?

Comment: Hmmm! Using my local IP address is not an option here. Isn't there any way I can set the URL without it being resolved, or as Sanchit5 said, is this simply impossible?

Comment: Technically this would be possible if I add javascript to my test.php and let the JS do the redirect. But then I have to set all the GET and POST parameters manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send the HTTP 1.1 header and that might be what's preventing the redirect from working. Your web server will add this one automatically because it needs to send the status code. Instead, pass the 307 status as header()'s third parameter:

```
header('location: http://localhost/some/url', true, 307);
```

The redirect headers are parsed by your browser, so "localhost" will be the same machine your browser is running on.

To pass all the GET parameters, you could append `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to the URL:

```
header('location: http://localhost/some/url?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], true, 307);
```

POST parameters are more complicated. You'll need to build your own URL by concatenating everything from the $_POST array. Be sure to urlencode() the values.

```
$redirect_url = 'http://localhost/some/url?';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $redirect_url .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}
header('location: ' . $redirect_url, true, 307);
```

And bear in mind you can only redirect a POST request as a GET. But if you're just building a mock for testing your gateway integration, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **localhost** as it is always being resolved by the client machine.

```
header('Location: http://localhost/dev/test.php');
```

Replace localhost by your server domain name like this:

```
header('Location: http://yourliveserver.com/dev/test.php');
```

Comment: No, I don't want to redirect to my live server, but my local machine.

Comment: You mean, you wanted to redirect the page from your live site to your local machine? Then use your local machine's ip address

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I can't use my own IP, since my router is too crappy to handle the DMZ and local resolving.